# "org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG" Error

Tags: android, xml, web-services, soap, ksoap2

In my application i am accessing some web services that are in my local system. When i am invoking this services from my PC, these all working abs fine but when these services called from another system. on the call i am receiving the error

> "org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException:
>   expected: START_TAG".

Here is my code:

```
    public String getAccountsNames(int billId){

        String value = new String();
        System.out.println("Inside getAccountsDetails method...........");
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("billId", billId);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet=true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        try
        {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive  resultString = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            value = resultString.toString();
            System.out.println("This getAccountsNames xmls is : "+xml);
        }   catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        return value;
   }
```

Also i have checked by setting SoapEnvelope.VER11, VER12, VER10. But the problem is same everytime.

Please suggest. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're not getting an XML response when you're on other systems. You can see what you're getting this way:

```
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
// ...
// execute the request
// ...
androidHttpTransport.responseDump; // <-- a string containing server response
```

Also: not that this might be the problem, but `AndroidHttpTransport` is deprecated, you should use `HttpTransportSE`.

Answer (score 0):

> AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

I had a similar issue and it was because I accidently inserted my NAMESPACE address instead of the URL, which was different. When I switched that back out, it worked.

As an added suggestion, if you are not seeing your parameter getting passed correctly, try excluding the line:

> soapEnvelope.dotNet=true;

for me, I had a boolean value that was constantly being passed as false until I commented that line out.